# Using assert to test if an error message was shown in JS

Tags: javascript, assert

Here's my js:

```
const assert = require('assert');

function sum(a, b) {
  if (typeof a !== 'number' || typeof b !== 'number') {
    throw new Error('parameters must be numbers');
  }

  return a + b;
}
```

How do I test if a message error was shown if I enter a string as a parameter? like sum(4,"5")?

I was trying to do something like this:

```
assert.strictEqual(sum(4, "5"), Error);
```

But the program stops it's execution with the message error of the function 'parameters must be numbers'. The thing is: when you use assert, if the condition passes the test, you should get no error message. Any ideas?

Comment: _but is not working._ What exactly is not working? "is not working"not a good description of a technical issue.

Comment: the program stops it's execution with the message error of the function 'parameters must be numbers'. but the thing is: when you use assert, if the condition passes the test, you should get no error message.

Comment: _..parameters must be numbers..._ So this is exactly what I expect your code to do.  _..if the condition passes the test..._ Yes but it doesn't pass the test as "5" is a string

Comment: yes, this is what i'm trying to fix. I am trying to use assert to test if a error message was shown when I call the function with "5" as a parameter

Comment: Just figured it out. Posted as an answer, take a look

Comment: For `assert.strictEqual(sum(4, "5"), Error);` the `structEqual` would never be called if `sum` throws an error. `sum` Has to return before `strictEqual` is called.

Answer (score 0):

```
assert.throws(() => {
  sum(4, '5');
});
```